# Uima Ruta Heading Levels

Tags: uima, ruta

I'm trying  to tag the Heading Levels (Level 1,Level 2,Level 3) from many headings. Using font size Information which is coming from HTML. First I took  font size  using regex  like

```
"<span style=\"font-family:\'(.+?)\'"->1=fontfamily;
"<span style=\"font-family(.+?)font-size:\'(.+?)\'"->2=font size;
```

Now I need to compare  all these heading sizes using fontsize information and tag heading levels based on it.

**Input:**

```
<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:'14pt'"><span class="">MATERIALS AND METHODS</span></span>
<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:'12pt'"><span class="">Chemicals</span></span>
<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:'10pt'"><span class="">HILIC-MS Profiling of Metabolites</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (tested with UIMA Ruta 2.5.0):

```
ENGINE utils.HtmlAnnotator;
TYPESYSTEM utils.HtmlTypeSystem;

CONFIGURE(HtmlAnnotator, "onlyContent" = false);
EXEC(HtmlAnnotator, {TAG});

DECLARE FontFamily;
DECLARE FontSize;
DECLARE Heading (INT level, INT size);

"<span style=\"font-family:\'(.+?)\'"->1=FontFamily;
"<span style=\"font-family(.+?)font-size:\'(\\d+.+?)\'"->2=FontSize;

INT size;
RETAINTYPE(MARKUP);

SPAN{-PARTOF(Heading) -> Heading, Heading.size = size}
    <-{FontFamily # FontSize{PARSE(size)};};
# h:Heading{-> size = h.size};
h:Heading{h.size == size -> Heading.level = 1};
h1:Heading{h1.level != 0} # h2:Heading.level == 0 
    {h1.size>h2.size -> h2.level = (h1.level + 1)};
h1:Heading{h1.level != 0} # h2:Heading.level == 0 
    {h1.size==h2.size -> h2.level = h1.level};
RETAINTYPE;
```

These rules use the HtmlAnnotator, which requires somewhat valid html. I needed to added `<html>` tags to the document in order to get it to work.

These rules are not optimal but just a starting point. The actual rules that you should use depend mainly on the use case and on how robust they need to be.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*